# Error pase de Variables Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Habitualmente envío formularios por ajax por el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#FormPubli').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'../phpAux/ProcesoPublicaPuesto.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:$(FormPubli).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
        $("#RespuestaPublica").html("Procesando Busqueda, espere por favor");
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (resp) {   
            if (resp.Registro < 1){
                //alert( "No pudo Cargarlo" );
                $("#RespuestaPublica").html("Algo Salio Mal..!");
                $("#RespuestaPublica").addClass("alert alert-warning");
                $("#RespuestaPublica").show();
                $("#RespuestaPublica").delay(8000).hide(600);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#RespuestaPublica").html(resp.Mensaje);
                $("#RespuestaPublica").addClass("alert alert-success");
                $("#RespuestaPublica").show();
                $("#RespuestaPublica").delay(5000).hide(600);
                $('#myModalForm1').delay(5000).modal('toggle');
                setTimeout('listar("No-Publicados")',100);
}
        },
    });
});});
```

EL tema es que siempre funciona bien, pero en este caso, tengo un formulario con 4 inputs que puedo cambiar los valores en dos (ValorCoe y ValorPrecio) y los otros dos son input  que se llenan con Jquery con un calculo cada vez que los campos ValorCoe y ValorPrecio, cambian de valor al ingresarlos.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ValorCoe" id="ValorCoe" placeholder="Coeficiente">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ValorPrecio" id="ValorPrecio" placeholder="Precio">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Resultado1" id="Resultado1" placeholder="Resultado1"disabled>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Resultado2" id="Resultado2" placeholder="Resultado2"disabled>
```

Los calculos se hacen correctamente y los valores se ven ya que se llenan correctamente a la vista en el formulario. Pero al hacer submint, los dos campos que surgen de las operaciones (Resultado1 y Resultado2), no se envían. Pensé que era un error en el nombre de los campos, pero no. Al inspeccionar el codigo en el google chrome, me doy cuenta que que en el headers del php que recibe los datos, esas variables nunca se enviaron. Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo `disabled` no integra las variables al formulario, si deseas que no pueda editarse, puedes sustituirlo por el atributo `readonly`

Comment: Buenisimo, no me di cuenta. MUCHAS GRACIAS